# React-Native: Keyboard pushes components up (Android only)

Tags: react-native

When i try to set value to 'vacuum' the keyboard pushes up the virtual joystick, which isn't happens on ios.
I tried to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">` in manifest and tried this guide either [link](https://openbase.io/js/react-native-android-keyboard-adjust) but  i dont have the `getPackage` method (neither understood the example usage).

Does anyone know how to solve this?
[image]

```
const SemiScreen = () => {
```

`const { setBrushSpeed, setVelSpeed } = useContext(SemiContext);
  const [vacuum, setVacuum] = useState(0);
  const [myX, setX] = useState(0);`

`return (`

```
  {/*This View contains the radioView and optionsView*/}
  <View style={styles.buttonsView}>
    {/*This View contains the radio elements */}
    <View style={styles.radioContainer}>
      <RadioButtons type="Velocity" callback={setVelSpeed} />
      <RadioButtons type="Brush" callback={setBrushSpeed} />
    </View>

    {/*This View contains the dislike and vacuum input*/}
    <View style={styles.optionsContainer}>
      {/*This View contains the input and apply button */}
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "column", marginHorizontal: 20 }}>
        <Input
          textContentType="telephoneNumber"
          containerStyle={styles.input}
          value={vacuum}
          placeholder="Vacuum"
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          returnKeyType="done"
          onChangeText={setVacuum}
        />
        <Button
          title="Apply"
          type="clear"
          onPress={() => {
            /*send topic with vacuum */
          }}
        />
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.dislike}
        onPress={() => {
          /*send topic*/
        }}
      >
        <AntDesign name="dislike2" size={50} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>

  {/*This View contains the joystick*/}
  <View style={styles.joystickView}>
    <AxisPad
      resetOnRelease={true}
      autoCenter={true}
      size={250}
      onValue={({ x, y }) => {
        // values are between -1 and 1
        //console.warn(x,y)
      }}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

);
};

Comment: Hello there, if my answer help you, please check it as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use following in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>
```

an exemple from an app i work in may it can help:

```xml
<application
      android:name="MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but unfortunately it doesn't work:

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.facebook.react">
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> </activity>

    <application />

</manifest>
`

Comment: You can see this code i've added, may be it can help, may be the position you putted the line is not good.